# replace web/app_dev,php is not working in symfony2

Tags: symfony

Good morning

i created a project where my url is

http:://my ip.address/jobs/web/app_dev.php/login will display my project login page 
 now i want to replace the url with www.jobs.com which should display the login page

```
ServerName www.jobs.com.localhost
DocumentRoot "/var/www/jobs/web"

<Directory /var/www/jobs/web>
   DirectoryIndex app.php
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

but when i type www.jobs.com.localhost in the url it is not coming can you just say me where i made a mistake

Comment: please review my answer and either mark is as correct or comment your problems with my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not directly symfony-related...

You have to make sure you have configured www.jobs.com.localhost to be in your hosts file.

The hosts file is a list of domains which's ip adresses shall not be resolved by your DNS / ISP.

It can usally be found at ...

```
  /etc/hosts                                # Linux / OSX
```

... or

```
 C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts      # Windows
```

Find this file and add the following line:

```
 127.0.0.1 www.jobs.com.localhost
```

If you have done so you can access www.jobs.com.localhost from your browser as long as you have a properly configured virtual host configured with ...

```
ServerName www.jobs.com.localhost
```

The second thing is ...

if you want your original your-ip/login page to display as the home-page ( your-ip/ or www.jobs.com.localhost/ without /login ) - you have 2 options.

**Option 1 - changing the login path**

```
# app/config/security.yml

security:
    firewalls:
        your_firewall_name:
            # ...
            login_path: /     # changed this /login to /
```

**Option 2 - disallowing access to all pages if not logged in**

```
# app/config/security.yml

security: 
    # ...
    access_control:
        # ...
        path: ^/, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED]
```

Now every user who has NOT logged in with his credentials during the current session ( role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY ) or has been automatically logged by 'remember me' ( IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED ) will be denied access to your page.

These users will automatically be redirected to the path configured at security.firewalls.your_firewall_name.login_path ( default: /login ) where your login-form resides!

Comment: Thank you i understand what you said